# Bug on a loop after few hours Discord.py rewrite (python)

Tags: python, loops, discord.py

Firstly I'm French, so sorry for my bad English

I have a problem. I did not succeed to make a normal Discord.py loop so I did one myself:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    game = discord.Game(f"{bot_version} | {len(client.guilds)} serveurs")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=game)
    print(f"Bot connecté en tant que : {client.user.name}")
    print(f"Le temps de chargement a été de : {loading_time} secondes")
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    #Loop part
    t = 0
    while not client.is_closed():
        for i in range(2):
            server_id = cursor.execute(f"SELECT server_id FROM 'servers' WHERE id={i+1}")
            server_id = server_id.fetchone()[0]
            server_id = int(server_id)
            #PV Démons
            ...
            ...
        #Time test
        print(t)
        t = t+4
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
```

**I condensed the code but in reality it's more than 150 lines.**

Ok now let's explain my problem:
So this code repeats every 4 seconds, but after 3/4 hours, it repeats twice every 4 seconds (video).
For my tests I made a variable to which I add 4 at the end of the loop. But after 3/4 hours, this variable is duplicated (video).

**So that are my questions :**

- Why this variable is duplicated?
- Why this code is repeated twice every 4 seconds?
- How I can fix that?
- How I can do normal loop on Discord.py Rewrite?

**Video :** [Video of the bug](https://youtu.be/zRWVtK-DBzw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation tells that the event: [on_ready()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_ready#discord.on_ready). Can be runned multiple times because of reconnection logic. Normally the bot doesnt reconnect in a few hours. This could explain why your problem only happens every 3/4 hours.

Further more the on_ready() function isnt made with the idea of having a infinite loop (or any kind of long running loop). As it is normally used for setting some things up. When a on_ready() function is taking more than 4 hours and suddenly it reconnects causing a new instance of on_ready() to be ran. You will see double the numbers as you explained. If we do want to use these long while loops. I recommend using tasks instead.

This would also solve the potential problem on_ready() event gives you. By only allowing 1 of that task to be running at a time.

[Tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers) are used for running stuff in the background. You can activate these tasks in the on_ready() function.

Make sure your on_ready function isnt doing background stuff in the future. And wont take more than a hour to complete. It is used for setting things up when ready. Not for running tasks in background (as explained there are other ways of achieving that).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response !!
I'm going to change that fast !
Just a last question : Do tasks work the same in the Rewrite version ?

Thank you !!

Comment: Well I gave a link: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers. This tells how to implement it. if you still have questions after trying to use tasks. Just start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

it probably repeats twice because you're doing this

```
for i in range(2):
```

you should be able to fix this by doing this instead

```
for i in range(1):
```

Comment: He tells that it loops perfectly the first 4 hours. In other words the for i in range(2) isnt causing problems.

Comment: he also asked why it's being repeated twice every 4 seconds, i thought that was a question on it's own